# Selenium webdriver C# CSS dropdown Issue - Element should have been select but was div

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html code as below.

```
<div class="rowElem fullSize ">
<div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper" style="z-index: 10; width: 276px;">
<div>
<span style="width: 245px;">MasterCard</span>
<a class="jqTransformSelectOpen" href="#"/>
</div>
<ul style="width: 274px; display: none; visibility: visible; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
<li><a class="selected" index="0" href="#">MasterCard</a></li>
<li><li><li>
</ul>
<select id="CardProvider" class="jqTransformHidden" name="CardKey" style="">
<option value="1">MasterCard</option>
<option value="2">VISA</option>
<option value="3">AMEX</option>
<option value="4">DEBIT</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Here, this is a dropdown menu where the //div/div/div has just one field displayed. 
//div/div/ul has four individual li which has the same provider input as the select tag.

I tried with a lot of combinations to choose a specific value from the drop down.

If I use //div/div[@select[id="CardProvider"]  with FindElement and it returns the very first value.

If I use //div/div/[@select[id]"cardProvider"]/ul//a - It is returning me with four values.

However I am not able to select the menu as the expected tag select but was div. If I write a query to bring the tagname as select, the text value returned as null.

I didnot give my selenium command as nothing worked and given the html for your reference. Kindly provide me your inputs to overcome this.

Comment: For those who want a real time example.. Have a look at http://flipkart.com Search drop down menu on the Top. The only difference is my html has a select tag and that dont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed a different approach (kind of workaround) of having two xpath to locate it and it works fine.

The Code I used is

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XPATH1ofCSSDROPDOWN)).Click();
            Driver.Wait(3000); 
            Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XPATH2ofDROPDOWNLISTELEMENT)).Click();
```

where XPATH2ofDROPDOWNLISTELEMENT = //*[@id='frmForm']//a[contains(text(), 'MasterCard')]

Kindly let me know if you have any answer apart from the one mentioned on the board.

Answer (score 2):

You can try avoid relative xpaths if those can be avoided.  In your html, the select element has a unique identifier, the id, which can be used.

You can try the below:

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElementById("CardProvider"));
sel.selectByVisibleText - there are options here to select by index, visible text and value - choose any which you think would be stable.
```

You can refer [this](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#user-input-filling-in-forms) for more.

Comment: Hi Nihariko. Thanks for your response, i tried this option .. but didnot work. as I mentioned it returns null input.

Answer (score 0):

frankly speaking I'd prefer usign css selectors.
**1st approach:**

```
String cssSelect="select[id='CardProvider']";
String cssMasterCard="select[id='CardProvider']>option[value='1']";
String cssVISA="select[id='CardProvider']>option[value='2']";

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelect)).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//clicking on e.g. MasterCard option
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssMasterCard)).click();
```

**2nd approach:**
if jQuery is supported you can click directly on menu options without clicking on menu dropdown previously:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+cssMasterCard+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

**3rd approach**
clicking using DOM model:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].click()");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

And dont forget to verify found xPaths or css selectors in firebug, firebug addon in firefox:

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hope this is the expected syntax I am searching for... Thanks Eugene for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works best in case of dropdown implemented without select

1. Click on drop down icon
2. wait for list to populate
3. now work on the list

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu']/div[@class='dropdown-menu-item']")).get(0).getText().equals("Option 1")

you need to put this in loop for all the menu items and works without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the icon
2. The list of elements gets exposed to Selenium
3. Pick one of those

I faced a similar problem in my code and the above steps fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String cssSelect="select[class='filerTableSelect']";
    String cssBetween="select[class='filerTableSelect']>option[value='BETWEEN']";
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelect)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssBetween)).click();
```

worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

First check that: Drop down in your UI/FrontEnd is using "select" method or not ?
   And if not then use below snippet that will click in drop down and select value.

WebElement selectMyElement = driver.findElement(this.getObject(By.Id("Id of Your DropDown")));
            selectMyElement.click();

```
        Actions keyDown = new Actions(driver);
        keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN)).perform();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
IWebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.Id("CardProvider"));
SelectElement clickThis = new SelectElement(dropDownListBox);
clickThis.SelectByText("MasterCard");
clickThis.SelectByText("VISA");
clickThis.SelectByText("AMEX");
clickThis.SelectByText("DEBIT");
```

Comment: Hi Abhi, Thanks for your response. I tried my input. but it failed. but i found a solution by having two different XPATH