# Selenium-webdriver java dropdown issue element should have been select

Tags: java, webdriver

I have HTML code for dropdown:

```
<div class="column two">
<select id="CCType" name="CCType">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="Mcard">Master Card</option>
    <option value="Visa ">VISA</option>
</select>
```

My script:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].select();", selectCreditCardType);
selectCreditCardType.selectByValue("Visa");
```

or

```
selectCreditCardType.selectByVisibleText(customer.creditCardType);
```

Result: Element should have been `select` but was `input`.

Tried different options from stackoverflow: [Selenium webdriver C# CSS dropdown Issue - Element should have been select but was div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505660/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-css-dropdown-issue-element-should-have-been-select)
But no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you utilize the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement class

C# example:

```
    var selElement = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement([Web Element goes here]);
    foreach (var option in selElement.Options)
    {
      if (option.Text == "desired text here")
         selElement.SelectByText(Option.Text);
    }
```

You can also do by value, but that would be a get attribute selection and comparison on the option of the select element.

```
    option.GetAttribute("value");
```